# If $a\sin x + b\cos(x+\theta) +b\cos(x-\theta) = d$, then what is the minimum value of $|\cos\theta|$?

Tags: trigonometry

> If $$a \sin x + b \cos(x+\theta)+ b \cos(x-\theta) = d$$
>   then what is the minimum value of $|\cos\theta|$?
>
> The answer is given: $\dfrac{\sqrt{d^2 - a^2}}{2|b|}$

I tried simplifying the equation to $a \sin x + 2b \cos\theta \cos x = d$, but I am stuck here. What must I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Using [Weierstrass Substitution](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Weierstrass_Substitution) and on rearrangement,

$$(d+2b\cos\theta)\tan^2\dfrac x2-2a\tan\dfrac x2+d-2b\cos\theta=0$$

As $\tan\dfrac x2$ is real the discriminant must be non-negative

Comment: It should be   d - 2bcos (theta), But, anyway this method is really good.

Comment: @JamilAhmed, Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 2):

$$d=a\sin x+2b\cos\theta\cos x=\sqrt{a^2+(2b\cos\theta)^2}\sin\left(x+\arcsin\dfrac{2b\cos\theta}{\sqrt{a^2+(2b\cos\theta)^2}}\right)$$

As for real $y,\sin y\le1$

$$\implies d\le\sqrt{a^2+(2b\cos\theta)^2}$$

Can you square both sides & rearrange?